# Splitting C code to statements using python

Tags: python, string, split

Is there any way to split a string (a complete C file) to C statements using python?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void) 
{
    if(final==(final_t))
    {
        foo(final);
        /*comment*/
        printf("equal\n");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

If this is read to a string is there any way to split it into a list of strings like this:

```
list=['#include <stdio.h>', '#include<math.h>', 'int main(void){','if(final==(final_t)){', 'foo(final);', '/*comment*/', 'printf("equal\n);', '}', 'return(0);', '}']
```

Comment: have you tried using `code.split('/n') `

Comment: Could you post what have you tried so far? check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Hint: You could start from splitting the file into lines, and from there do some logic based on `;`, `{`,  `}` (this is a simplistic approach; you could also take strings and comments into account).

Comment: Neither of the responses are taking into account that 1) a statement may span into multiple lines, 2) a line may contain multiple statements, 3) statements may be deeply nested, 4) string literals and comments may include something that look like statements etc. In short, you seem to need a parser, something like [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser) (disclaimer: that's the first parser I found, it may or may not work).

Comment: what is *statement* in your context?

Answer (score 1):

Without being extremely complex, a C language program is composed of lexical tokens that form declarations and statements according to a syntax. And your splitting need some more explainations: according to the C language standard, `if (cond) statement1 [else statement2];` **is** is statement. Simply both statement1 and statement2 can be blocks, so statements can be nested. In your requirements, you seem to concat the opening brace of a eventual block to the conditional, and leave the closing brace alone. And you say nothing about declarations or preprocessor language

So IMHO, your specifications are still incomplete...

Anyway, it is already far too complex for a simple lexical analyzer. So you should first write the complete grammar that you want to process, ideally in Backus-Naur Form, and declare the terminating tokens. Once you have that, it is easy to use <del>lex + yaxx</del> PYL to build a parser from that grammar.

It is probably not the expected answer, but C language parsers are far from trivial, except you want only accept a small subset of the language.

Comment: Yes I understand that the C statements are not exactly what I am asking. Thats why I included an example to explain the problem. Anyway thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

You should perform the following steps to reach the result:

1. Get your code as separate lines.
2. Cut leading and trailing spaces.
3. Skip empty lines.

If your code if given as a string you can use:

```
lines = content.split('\n')
```

If as a file:

```
with open('file.c') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

To cut extra spaces:

```
lines = list(map(str.strip, lines))
```

To skip empty lines:

```
lines = list(filter(lambda x: x, lines))
```

So the full code may look like this:

```
content = """
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void) 
{
   if(final==(final_t))
   {
    foo(final);
    printf("equal\n");
   }
   return(0);
}
"""

lines = content.split('\n')
lines = list(map(str.strip, lines))
lines = list(filter(lambda x: x, lines))

print(lines)
```

Comment: This only splits the string into lines and stores those lines. What happens if there is a statement which is more than one line?

Comment: It depends what you mean by statement. Because statements in C are nested generally, so it's more a tree than a list you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
code_list = []

with open("<your-code-file>", 'r') as code_file:
    for line in code_file:
        if "{" in line:
            code_list[-1] = code_list[-1] + line.strip()
        else:
            code_list.append(line.strip())

print(code_list)
```

output:

```
['#include <stdio.h>', '#include <math.h>', '', 'int main (void){\n', 'if(final==(final_t))   {\n', 'foo(final);', 'printf("equal\\n");', '}', 'return(0);', '}']
```

Comment: How will it handle `printf("Hello {%s}\n", "world")`?

Comment: If it surrounded by apostrophes - ignore the "if" that's about the "{"